# Scripting iphoto for face detection?

Tags: photos.app

A coworker just asked me if I could help him script iPhoto, but I'm totally inexperienced with iPhoto and with scripting apps. He has thousands of photos and he needs to filter out those that do not have faces, and for the remaining photos he has some sort of template that centers the faces in a nice frame. He then saves the results to disk then repeats. It is painful to watch it do it by hand and I really want to help him out as it seems like something that could be automated, however, I have no idea where to start.

Does anyone have any ideas on a good way to go about this? I searched here but didn't find anything that helped. A high level overview would be great, but I wouldn't overlook anything with specific details! Thanks!

UPDATE:

Maybe a better question is: Does anyone know of an easy OSX solution for finding all photos in a collection that have faces and then to crop them around the face and save out a new image for each face?

Comment: I haven't worked with the latest versions of iPhoto, but earlier versions were painfully unscriptable. :(

Comment: Thanks for the background, Daniel. So far, I think my best bet is to find some open source image tools and write scripts.

Comment: FYI, the latest versions of iPhoto *do* have a scripting dictionary. I haven't played around with it much yet, though.